# How do I commit with a utf-8 message file?

Tags: svn, vim, utf-8, internationalization, cmd

I am trying to commit a revision with subversion on cmd.exe. The cmd.exe's codepage is utf-8 (set with `chcp 65001`):

```
c:\path\to\work\dir> svn ci
```

Since I have not specified a message with the `-m` flag, and the variable `SVN_EDITOR` is set to *gvim*, gvim opens and I can enter my message. I save the file as *utf-8* (`:set filencoding=utf8`) and quit the editor.

Now, the svn client (?) tells me: `Auf ... .folgte ein nicht-ASCII Byte 195, das nicht von/nach UTF-8 konvertiert werden konnte` (which I believe in English to be: *Non-ASCII character (code %d) detected, and unable to convert to/from UTF-8*).

This is strange since I am quite sure that the message file I stored is in UTF-8 format.

I also tried storing it in *latin-1*, but with the same effect.

**Edit**

I did a test with the message `ü`. The hex content of the file is

```
0000000: c3bc 0d0a 2d2d 2044 6965 7365 2075 6e64  ....-- Diese und
0000010: 2064 6965 2066 6f6c 6765 6e64 656e 205a   die folgenden Z
0000020: 6569 6c65 6e20 7765 7264 656e 2069 676e  eilen werden ign
0000030: 6f72 6965 7274 202d 2d0d 0a0d 0a41 2020  oriert --....A
0000040: 2020 780d 0a                               x..
```

Note the first for characters (`ü` followed by `\x0d\x0a`). The `ü` is encoded as `c3 bc` which is the utf-8 representation for *LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS* (see [utf 8 table](http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/)) which is the desired `ü`.

Note also, that the error message (in this new case: `Ein Nicht-ASCII Zeichen (Kode 195) wurde gefunden, das nicht von/nach UTF-8 konvertiert werden konnte`) complains about 195 (which is decimal for `c3`, the very first byte in the file). Of course, the error message is right: it is no ASCII character, but is this not the whole point of using utf-8 files?

**Edit 2**

I tried to commit the message in UTF-8 format because this was the what I believed to be most natural thing. Obviously, SVN, at least on cmd.exe, doesn't think so. I couldn't care less what format I need to commit the message in, as long as I can commit an `ü` and other german special characters.

Comment: can svn import text without umlaute (pure ASCII)?

Comment: Yes, if I have a commit message without umlaute, I can commit the revision.

Comment: so you can change `ü` --> `ue`, `ö` --> `oe`, `ä` --> `ae` and `ß` --> `ss`.

Comment: I am deeply impressed how far we've come with i18n.

Comment: so we can speak about a better world or going to get solutions for the issues in this world  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the `svn commit` command actually accepts an argument to tell SVN what encoding your commit message is in. Try `svn commit --encoding UTF-8`.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html says:

> --encoding ENC
>
> Tells Subversion that your commit message is composed using the character encoding provided.
>   The default character encoding is derived from your operating system's native locale; **use**
>    **this option if your commit message is composed using any other encoding**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work, but you can try also using `:set bomb` in your gvim to include a BOM in the file when you save. Some programs use a BOM to detect that they should use Unicode. I'm not sure if SVN falls into that category or not.

Comment: This does not work: the *BOM* is `0xef 0xbb` (Decimal 239 187). SVN doesn't manage to read the very first character 239 (`Ein Nicht-ASCII Zeichen (Kode 239) wurde gefunden, das nicht von/nach UTF-8 konvertiert werden konnte`)

Comment: That's a shame. It was worth a shot I guess.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [iconv for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm):

File before conversion:

```
Ã¼
-- Diese und die folgenden Zeilen werden ignoriert --
```

hexdump:

```
00000000  c3 bc 0d 0a 2d 2d 20 44  69 65 73 65 20 75 6e 64  |Ã¼..-- Diese und|
00000010  20 64 69 65 20 66 6f 6c  67 65 6e 64 65 6e 20 5a  | die folgenden Z|
00000020  65 69 6c 65 6e 20 77 65  72 64 65 6e 20 69 67 6e  |eilen werden ign|
00000030  6f 72 69 65 72 74 20 2d  2d 0d 0a                 |oriert --..|
```

conversion command:

```
<utf8.txt iconv -f utf-8 -t 850>ascii.txt
```

result:

```
ü
-- Diese und die folgenden Zeilen werden ignoriert --
```

hexdump:

```
00000000  81 0d 0a 2d 2d 20 44 69  65 73 65 20 75 6e 64 20  |...-- Diese und |
00000010  64 69 65 20 66 6f 6c 67  65 6e 64 65 6e 20 5a 65  |die folgenden Ze|
00000020  69 6c 65 6e 20 77 65 72  64 65 6e 20 69 67 6e 6f  |ilen werden igno|
00000030  72 69 65 72 74 20 2d 2d  0d 0a                    |riert --..|
```

Codepage was always 850.

Comment: This doesn't help, either. SVN now complains about `129 nicht gefunden` which is `ü` in *Codepage 850* (or `0x81` in hex)

Comment: ok, so you must figure out, what text format your prog needs.

Comment: Yes, that's basically my question.

Answer (score 0):

add to `.bashrc` (or similiar)

```
export LANG="de_DE.utf8"
export LANGUAGE="de_DE.utf8"
export LC_ALL="de_DE.utf8"
```

svn uses encoding defined in enviroment